# Can`t play a song Spotify SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

I want to play some songs from Spotify, I just have the login section, I get the token and everything but I can't play any song.

I have followed this tutorial (http://sonien.net/wordpress/using-spotify-ios-sdk-swift-ios-9/) and I have some errors.

1.- Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

```
self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.init(clientId: SPTAuth.defaultInstance().clientID)
```

2.- Value of type 'SPTAudioStreamingController' has no member 'loginWithSession'

```
player.loginWithSession(session, callback: self.didLogin)
```

so I changed to:

```
player.login(withAccessToken: String(session))
```

and I think i solved the error

I'm using Swift 3 with Xcode 8

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem with initializing an instance of the SPTAudioStreamingController. This is because the SDK requires that you init a **SharedInstance** of the object first before you can access any of its methods. This is because the SPTAudioStreamingController class is a Singleton class, meaning it can only be instantiated once throughout the lifetime of the application.

The proper syntax for this in the SDK is:

```
player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
```

Hope this was helpful!